# Cannot execute procedure in oracle 10g says Table or View does not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, toad

I have an Oracle database which was already created and designed by someone else previously, in my company. My problem is that some procedures are not executing. I'm getting the error:

> Table  or procedure or view does not exist

But, I can see those procedures from Toad. I already tried to grant some privileges from `sysdba`, the result is the same; I get the same error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are able to see the procedures in Toad, then try to see what is the status of those and try to compile and see whether you are getting any errors.

Comment: I have tried to compile too and still getting the error from Toad @Polppan

Comment: In Toad what are the status of your procedures? BTW who is the owner of these procedures? The same user which are logged into?

Comment: there are 2 users in total; capps & pthm. Owner of those problematic procedures is "pthm" whereas the tables that are accessed by those procedures belong to "capps". I want to execute the procedures from "pthm".@Polppan

Comment: Are you prefixing the procedure name with the owning schema name? Do those that work have synonyms? It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing; adding a sample procedure specifications and owner, how you're trying to call it, and who as might help.

Comment: @user2444568 As Alex pointed out providing procedure code and how you are calling the procedure will help others to identity the problem.